# Trying to fetch APi but it is not displaying the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api

I have created Context API I am trying to fetch the data from my API so I can use the state globally, but is not doing it.  I am not getting any errors in the console. But when I try to fetch from the Other Component, I am getting data in the console. Just in the Context, I am not getting it.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect}from 'react'
import ITrucks from '../interface/truck';
import axios from 'axios';

export const TrucksContext=  React.createContext({})

export const TrucksProvider:React.FC = ({ children }  ) => {

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [trucks, setTrucks] =useState<ITrucks[]>([])
const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
const fetchData = () => {
  axios
    .get('https://localhost:7000/trucks')
    .then((response) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setTrucks(response.data);
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setIsError(true);
      console.log(error);
    });
};
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
   


  return (

  
    <TrucksContext.Provider
      value={{trucks}}
    >
    <>
      {children}
      </>
    </TrucksContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `setTrucks([...response.data])`

Comment: It is working, could you please explain this

Comment: Awesome. I can't be as detailed as a lot of people on here, but the three dots are the javascript 'spread operator'. Since your original state contains an empty array, that [...response.data] is basically telling the original state array to be filled with this new array's data (response.data). If anyone can further explain, feel free.

Comment: I understand that

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in the API itself. When an API has an error it often return empty data to Axios instead of an error, it depends on the return statement

Comment: There is some problem with the  context, When I try to fetch the data in some of the other Components that I have in the project I am getting the data